# How to set Order categories of custom toolpart

Tags: 2013, development, visual-web-part, toolpart

I Created Custom WebPart Property for SharePoint Visual WebPart with this code ([here - full code](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/23/create-custom-web-part-properties-for-visual-webpart-sharepoint2013/))

```
[WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Project ID"), 
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
Category("Project Settings")]
public string projectID { get; set; }
```

the result is this

[image]

but, I want my custom propertis display in first of categories. 
like this

[image]

I know can use custome EditorPart ([editorPart - code](https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/web-part-properties-editorpart/)), but it's Requires me to customize each control...

someone know how do to it

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the appearance of your properties in the tool pane by doing the following:

- Expanding and collapsing specific categories when the pane opens.
  Use the Expand method of either the WebPartToolPart or CustomPropertyToolpart class to expand selected categories.
- Hiding base class properties.
  Use the Hide method of the WebPartToolPart class to hide selected properties.
- Controlling the order of tool parts within a tool pane. (this what you need !)

To controlling the order of tool parts within a tool pane as you want, you should retrieve the tool pane in the array passed to the `GetToolParts` method of the `WebPart class`. as something like this code:

```
public override Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
        { 
            //A 3 elements array to hold 3 properties pane in the toolpart
            Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[] allToolParts = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[3];

                //Toolpart for Default properties for every webpart
                Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartToolPart standardToolPart = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartToolPart();
                //Toolpart for Custom properties for every webpart
                Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.CustomPropertyToolPart customToolParts = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.CustomPropertyToolPart();
                allToolParts[0] = standardToolPart;
                allToolParts[1] = customToolParts;
                //our custom toolpart
                allToolParts[2] = new CustomToolPart();
                return allToolParts;

        }
```

- Check full example [Creating a Custom ToolPart for a Custom Web Part](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/01/30/sharepoint-creating-a-custom-toolpart-for-a-custom-web-part-aspx/)
- See also [Creating a Web Part with a Custom Tool Part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178(v=office.11).aspx)
- Ref : [Best Practices for Developing Web Parts for SharePoint Products and Technologies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583135(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: for GetToolParts method, need to use WebPart of **Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart**. and not System.Web.Ui.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart